# How to use ActiveRecord for Multiple Environment outside Rails?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have created a DB connection without rails for single environment and it is working fine. but want to create DB configuration for multiple environment (Ex. development, production, test etc.)

single environment db connection code (which is working fine):

```
require 'mysql2'
require "active_record"

# Using ActiveRecord

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter=> 'mysql2',
:database=> 'dev_db',
:username=> 'root',
:password=>'root'
)


class Planning < ActiveRecord::Base
end


p Planning.find(1)
```

suggestion accepted...

Comment: Are you working within any other framework, or is this all custom-built? (The technique will be pretty much the same regardless; I'm just wondering if anything will be pre-defined already.)

Comment: no framework only ruby

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891529/standalone-ruby-how-to-load-different-environments-from-database-yml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What rails does may look like magic, but it's actually very simple (well, this case, at least). Here's the outline:

At startup, app loads all available database configurations. By convention, they are stored in YAML format in `config/database.yml`.

Then, current environment is determined. The easiest way to do this is environment variables. For example:

```
 MY_ENV=production ruby my_script.rb
```

Then, in the script, you fetch current env, pick corresponding connection configuration and use it to connect.

```
connection_configs = YAML.load(File.read('config/database.yml'))
current_env = ENV['MY_ENV'] || 'development' # if no value, assume development mode
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(connection_configs[current_env])
```

Comment: for reference : `connection_configs = YAML.load(File.read('config/database.yml'))`

Comment: @GaganGami: this better be in the answer. Thanks for writing it out 